# Remove blank space in WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I have edited a lot in that WordPress theme but i have faced a problem in removing that blank space between sidebar and main content of the site like you see in picture below.

[image]

I have tried to edit the float and decrease margin , padding but that doesn't work 
I think i am looking in different direction 
any help would be appreciated.

link of `css`

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see the markup and css working together. Maybe create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demo the problem.

Comment: actually i am a beginner to this stuff i can't create jsfddle .. i already add the style.css file and here is the link of my site <www.egy-cash.com/beta/wordpress/>

Comment: You should use any web developer plugin of your browser to identify the problematic object. In IE, press F12, in Firefox STRG-Alt-C, in Chrome Strg-Shift-i

Comment: thanks @MichaelWagner that helps me identify the problem i just added a postion css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked a bit over your website. Firstly, you want to remove the 170px `right-margin` from `.content`. Than you can edit the `width` of `.sidebar-primary` to fit in the space.

```
@media all and (min-width: 1140px) {
    .site-container .content { 
        margin-right: 10px; 
        }
    .site-container .sidebar-primary { 
        width: 330px; 
        }
    }
```

As a sidenote, I noticed your site has big responsiveness issues on widths lower than 1140px.